# Username escaping playpen!

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, display-names

I've noticed [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661872/laec-h0ne)'s username is, well, escaping.

[image]

See what I mean?

I have no idea how they are accomplishing this, but it does lead to an unnatural, to say the least, effect on their questions and answers - and especially comment threads.

Comment: Can you say Zalgo?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Zalgo? Huh?

Comment: @Undo H͇̼̖͋̎̾͊̆̂e̯͔̲͍͛̐ͮ̈́̚ ̱̲ͥw͖̫̻̼͇h̬̣͓̩̩͒́̉̚͡o̰̦͎͉̥̅͌̊̄̓̈͢ ͍̫̋͌̎̂̏̏ͮW̶̥̩̰͍ͪ͌a͎͍̭̪̯̳͌͊͑ͪ̈ͅi̠̫̎̇̾̓t̍͏̭̭̪̞͕͓s̘̬͓̳̭ͣ ̹͓̺̣̥͉̫̌̊ͨ͗̍B̙̯̲ͯ̑ͭ̈ͧͩ͐͞é̙h͒̈ͮį̖̟͚̭̗̰̀ͮ̌ͯͪǹ̳͌ͮ͢d̼̤̒̇̆̄̀͛ͮ ̹̩͔͚̭͖ͯ͆̽ͥ͆̚ͅT̞͔̺̞̜̲̤ͦͯ͋̽͒h̝̠̲̟̉̆ͬͥ̈͝e̲̣̤̘̞͙̽ͬͯͤͯ͊ ̟̫̪̺̈̃ͣ̋͡W͉͙̗͈̘ͬá̯̟̰̦ḷ̞̖̠̫͒ͯ̿ͥͩ̏͟l̵͙̜̰͓͉͓̑̿ͣ̇.͎͕̲̮̣͗͂̕

Comment: OK, how are you doing that? That's no ASCII that I know of...

Comment: T̗͙͉̮ͯͯ̒̒ͯͣ͌ͩ̌̌h̥͇͖̟͉̮͎͋̅̿̉̆̌ͤͨ͒͋̉̉e̼̺̻̺̙̼̮̣̞̠ͤ͋̅̂ͦ͒͊̽ͦ̏ ̹̱̣͉̮̭̱͇͔̭̩̭͙̳͔̩̣̲̾͌ͬͬͥc̗̤̫͈͇̙ͣ̽ͤ̓̔̿̇ͩͤ̓͌̏̾ͯ̒̈e͓̻̟̭͔̥̘̿͛͊ͬͥ̎̇̾̌̌ͧͬ̌͊ͪ̊̎ͮn̟̝̻̥̈̆̓͗̒̆͗͋̈́ͯͯͪ͒̑t͍̳͉̘̋̿̋͛̎̏ͬ̓͛ͯ̃ͨ̄͒̈́͛̚é͈̹͈̼̯̱͎̫͈̫͇͈̳͇̩ͮͬ͗ͯ̑ͪ̾ͥ̚ͅř͔̣̻̬̬̜̐̓ͧ̆̉ͥ̉ ̰̦̳̮̘̜̻͍͚̰͔͉̘̫̈́͂͊̔̒̇ͥͬͅc̳̣̪̭̪̈ͪ͊̀͊̔ͅa͚̭͚̦͓̮̰̩̞͇̜͚͚̪̘̲̞ͪ́͂̓ͣn̗̱̩̣̘̞͉̭̱̣̣͍̫̂ͯ̐ͣ̎͗ͮ̆̒̀̄̔ͦ͗n̮͙̥͕̘̖̦͎͉̠̱̻̗̫ͩ̓̂̔͌̇̄̐͂ͬͩ̄̉ͅö̬͎̭̝̠͍͚̯͕̪̼͉̦͚̯̼ͫͫ͆ͅt͖͈̠̼̼͉̳͚͙͙̳̘̟̳̙͔̟̍͆̆̃͛ͥͭ̎ͤ̅ ̺͔̠̞̖̦̲͈̣̻̰͙͙ͮ͗̏̎͊̏̊̎͐͊ͤ͂̌͛͗̎ͪh̪̖̰͚̦̫̼͖̆ͩ̈́͗́ͅo̞̫̟͎͉̯͙̤̗̜̖͂͋̌̂ͥ̈ͨ̿̎͗͒̎͂l̟͓͓̖͖̖̫͙̹̰̼͕͈͈͍̭̗̲̆ͯ̈d̘̮̰͚̃̈́͋̂ͪͤ́ͯ̎ͭͬ̓̊̔ͭ̂̚

Comment: STOP!!! Just post an answer and tell me how this annoyance is achieved!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579844/how-does-zalgo-text-work

Comment: That's great stuff, how long will people be able to use it before it gets banned?

Comment: Fortunately, [a little goes a long way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/102937).

Comment: @apaul34208 No, the right question is how long will people be able to use it before *they* get banned.

Comment: @undo good point